# Can't Update ANYTHING on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, updates

I have a working version of Wordpress on my home Synology web server, and I can view the site and post comments etc without any problem.

However, I cannot update any plugins or themes and also can't add any new plugins or themes.  I keep getting the error saying "Installation failed: could not copy file..."  The name of the file it fails to copy changes each time.

I have verified that I do have FTP access and all my permissions across the files/folders seem to be precisely correct (664 for files, 775 for folders).

The only seemingly significant bread crumb I have found is this: Checking my FTP transfer log files, I see that there are files being added to the correct directories BUT then they are IMMEDIATELY being deleted from those same directories ('put' followed by 'delete').  So it seems like it is connecting to the web server, installing the files, and then immediately uninstalling everything!!

I sincerely appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: Try [SF]. This is not fit for SO!

Comment: Sorry Grant, thanks for redirecting me.

Comment: I was wrong anyway. [wordpress.SE] has it's own site. You should get experts in Wordpress over there.